# Javascript for(). am I missing something, or this just not working this way

Tags: javascript, json

was curious about this one if really didn't work this way:

```
  var key, i = 0;
  for(key in data.user) {
    if(data.user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(`No: ${i} - ${data.user[i].name}`);
      i++;
    }
  }
```

code above is not working, however if i put manually `${data.user[0].name` it will give me the value.

but this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   console.log(data[i].name);
}
```

code above will work for exactly what I need, but I'm just curious about the first code. It seems to be working for me.

Thanks!

Comment: A `console.log(key, user)` inside your for loop would really help := Learn to debug your own code

Comment: `if(data.user.hasOwnProperty(user))` what is `user`? is it a string? did you mean `key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed user in for the key:

```
  for(var key in data.user) {
    if(data.user.hasOwnProperty(key))
      console.log(`No: ${key} - ${data.user[key].name}`);
  }
```

Comment: I realize I messed up something and didn't check properly, thanks for the explaination!